# WSO2 API Manager - API-specific configuration files

Tags: wso2-api-manager

We use a configuration management tool (Chef) for WSO2 API Manager installation (v2.1.0). For each installation, the WSO directory is deleted and overwritten with the new changes / patches.

This process removes already created APIs from the WSO2 API Publisher. (Since these are still present in the database, they cannot be re-created with the same name.) We have assumed that the entire API configuration is stored in the database which is obviously not the case.

This API-specific file is noticeable to us:

> <wso2am>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--my-api-definition_vv1.xml

Are there any other such files that must not be deleted during a new installation or is there a way to create these files from the information stored in the database?

We have considered using the "API import / export tool" (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment). However, according to documentation, this also creates the database entries for the API, which in our case already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep the content of the server folder (/repository/deployment/server). For this, you can use SVN based [dep-sync](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer). Once you enable dep-sync by giving an SVN server location, all the server specific data will be written to the SVN server.

When you are installing the newer pack, what you need to do is to point to the svn location and the database. (I hope you are using a production-ready database other than inbuilt h2)

Comment: Pubci, thank you for your fast reply. dep-sync does the trick. (And yes, we're using a production-ready database.)